# Difference between these two regular expressions?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

What's the difference between these two regular expressions?(using php preg_match())

`/^[0-9\x{06F0}-\x{06F9}]{1,}$/u`

`/^[0-9\x{06F0}-\x{06F9}\x]{1,}$/u`

What's the meaning of the last `\x` in the second pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's interpreted as `\x00` (the null character) but it's almost certainly a bug caused by sloppy editing or copy and paste.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

> ...Since \x by itself is not a valid regex token...

Answer (score 0):

I think the second pattern is not valid.

According to this page http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html, the \x is only useful followed by the unicode number:

> Since \x by itself is not a valid regex token, \x{1234} can never be
>   confused to match \x 1234 times.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird. Php notation for a unicode character is \x{}. In perl, it is the same thing.

But php has the //u modifier in regex's. I asume that means unicode. No such modifier in perl.

In perl regex, \x## is parsed, where ## is required to denote an ascii character. If its \x or \x#, its a warning of illeagal hex digit ignored (because it requires 2 digits, no more no less) and it takes only the valid hex digits in the sequence. If you have no digits as in \x, it uses \0 ascii char etc..

However, any \x{} notation is ok, and \x{0} is equivalend to \x{}. And \x{0}-\x{ff} is considered ascii, \x{100}- is considered unicode.

So, \x is a valid hex/unicode escape sequence but by itself its asumed hex and is incomplete and probably not something that should be left to parser default mechanisms.

Comment: @hobbs - Thanks for the heads up. My version 5.10 has /imsxpgc, new in 5.14 /adlu - /imsxadlupgc. The old version, promotion to Unicode rules could be automatic by target or pattern UTF-8 encodings or platform. So /\x{100}/u seems redundant except apparently, (?u: ) is possible. What happens to automatic promotion on both sides now, I don't know. 5.10 does have bugs that were fixed so maybe I upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the second `\x` is actually an invalid character. Do both expressions work?